# Angular2 ngFor, property undefined when exist

Tags: angular, typescript

Im dealing with problem. I get one of my propertys as "undefined" when it is defined and i cant find a solution for it:

I have parent component with data:

```
    @Component({
      selector: "app-my-products",
      templateUrl: "./my-products.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./my-products.component.css"]
    })
    export class MyProductsComponent implements OnInit {
      watched: WatchedProduct[] = [];
      products: Product[] = [];
      watchedProducts: Product[] = [];
      ratings: ProductAvarageRating[] = [];
//then, i get data. It works fine
```

In Parent.Component.html i call two child component like that with data:

```
<div>
        <app-my-products-ratings
              [watchedProducts]="watchedProducts"
              [ratings]="ratings"
            ></app-my-products-ratings>

            <app-my-products-watched
              [watchedProducts]="watchedProducts"
            ></app-my-products-watched>
</div>
```

`MyProductsWatched.component.ts` looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-my-products-watched",
  templateUrl: "./my-products-watched.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./my-products-watched.component.css"]
 })
export class MyProductsWatchedComponent implements OnInit {
  products: Product[] = [];
  watched: WatchedProduct[] = [];
  selectedProduct = new Product();
  @Input() watchedProducts: WatchedProduct[] = []; //data from Parent here
```

And his html:

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let product of watchedProducts">
    <button mat-button>{{ product.name }}</button>
</mat-list-item>
```

it works fine. But in `MyProductRatings.component.html` i get an error, that one of property from `ratings` are undefined.

Component of `MyProductRatings`:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-my-products-ratings",
  templateUrl: "./my-products-ratings.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./my-products-ratings.component.css"]
 })
export class MyProductsRatingsComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() watchedProducts: WatchedProduct[] = [];
   @Input() ratings: ProductAvarageRating[] = []; //data from parent here
```

Html:

```
<div>
  <mat-selection-list>
    <mat-list-item
      *ngFor="
        let product of (watchedProducts | search: searchText);
        let i = index
      "
    >
      <button mat-button>{{ watchedProducts[i].name }}</button>
      {{ ratings[i].avarageRating }}
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-selection-list>
</div>
```

What i want to do, is to get property named `avarageRating` from `ratings` based on `index` from `*ngFor` loop.

For example, now i have 2 items in `watchedProducts`. Error that i get in html in `MyProductRatings.component.html` is:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'avarageRating' of undefined

But i get that rating properly (everything displays fine).

My question is, what i do wrong, that i get that errors in my conosole?

Comment: Use *ngIf="ratings[i]" before you have {{ratings[i].averageRating}} - the error in the console means ratings[i] might not exist for all the i values like you expect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your watchedProducts loads before avarageRating. Either change the way you load the data so that avarageRating loads then watchedProducts. Or simply add a *ngIf="ratings[i]" so its more like

```
<span> *ngIf="ratings[i]">{{ ratings[i].avarageRating }} </span>
```

It's better to do the later because it solves the problem if the number of ratings doesn't equal the number of watchedProducts. You will protect yourself from an index out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over **watchedProducts** array and based on the index of this array want to get value out of **ratings** array. Now there could be any scenario, for example, **watchProducts** has more items than **rattings** array in that case you would get index out of range exception, or **ratings** array has no item in that case you would get 'cant' get property of undefined'. So its best practice to make sure the **ratings** array has value before getting it.

You could modify the code       {{ ratings[i].avarageRating }} with this one

```
      {{ GetAverageRatings(i) }}
```

and in your component.ts file you could write the function like this

```
GetAverageRatings(index:number)
{
if(this.ratings[index])
{
return this.ratings[index];
}
}
```

Thanks.